# Displaying a spinner when changing dropdown list selection not working | React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

I have a dropdown list where I have an onChange event, the onchange event is firing 2 functions, one to set the state of the spinner to be shown, the other to contact a web service, and passing a call back to hide the spinner. However the spinner is always hidden and never set to true. Here's my code:

```
const Root = (props: IRootProps) => {
    const [displaySpinner, setDisplaySpinner] = React.useState(false)

    const _getOfficeDetails = async (locationId: string, callback?: () => void) => {
        //do something here then call the callback
        callback()
    }

    return (
        <>
                <Dropdown
                    options={utils.getDropDownOptions(offices.map((o => { return { key: o.id, text: o.name } })), "")}
                    selectedKey={officeDetails ? officeDetails.id : 0}
                    onChange={(e, opt) => {
                        setDisplaySpinner(true);
                        _getOfficeDetails(opt.key.toString(), () => setDisplaySpinner(false))
                    }
                    }
                />
                {displaySpinner &&
                    <>
                        <br />
                        <Spinner size={SpinnerSize.large} />
                    </>
                }
        </>
    )
}
```

displaySpinner will always be false, although the onChange is fired and the breakpoint stops on the setDisplaySpinner.. I never see the spinner.. I tried to add setTimeout for 5000 ms to see if it would work or if it appears quickly and disappears, but same. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are not really waiting on the callback with your spinner.
`setDisplaySpinner` is set to true and immediately is changed back to false. You want to make sure that it's waiting for the async action to complete. So I haven't tested it, but this should work:

1. remove both `setDisplaySpinner` from the `onChange`.
2. update `_getOfficeDetails` as follows:

```
    const _getOfficeDetails = async (locationId: string, callback?: () => void) => {
        setDisplaySpinner(true);
        //do something here then call the callback
        await callback();
        setDisplaySpinner(false);        
    }
```